# Pretty printing with Sagemath command line

Tags: symbolic-math, sage

How do I "pretty-print" something in the Sagemath command line (as in sympy)? The only solution I found was to use `get_test_shell()` function, according to [this entry](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/sage/repl/display/formatter.html) in the docs. But basically I have to use

```
from sage.repl.interpreter import get_test_shell
shell = get_test_shell()
shell.run_cell('%display ascii_art')
shell.run_cell('integral(x^2/pi^x, x)')
```

I find this to be too cumbersome (4 complicated lines just to display things nicely!) and what you want to display even has to be given as a string. So I'm looking for an easier alternative. I'm sure there's another way; I just can't find it.

I think I might be using the wrong terms because according to the manual itself:

> > Pretty printing means
> >         rendering things so that MathJax or some other latex-aware front end
> >         can render real math.

So if I use `pretty_print_default(True)` it's going to always print latex, which isn't what I want for now.

One thing I tried that I thought would work was to do

```
from sympy import pretty_print
```

Which should use Sympy's pretty-print (which is what I actually want), but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran across the problem that we want to be able to doctest things that are interactive by their nature.  Try just this at the command line:

```
sage: %display ascii_art
sage: integral(x^2/pi^x, x)

 / 2    2                      \  -x*log(pi) 
-\x *log (pi) + 2*x*log(pi) + 2/*e           
---------------------------------------------
                      3                      
                   log (pi)
```

This is one of the "magic" percent directives in IPython.  I agree it could be documented better.

Comment: I've opened https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/23298 to hopefully improve this documentation.  You searched well to find that!  It's non-obvious.

Comment: Works perfectly. I appreciate you opening that issue. I just now got that this is what the `shell.run_cell('%display ascii_art')` line does! I don't understand why this is done in such a cumbersome manner in the doc, being that your way (I believe) is pretty much equivalent.

Comment: (As I point out above, I think that is the only way to *test* that this works automatically when we run our test suite. Agreed it is confusing.)

Comment: Just noticed that it doesn't pretty-print anything that has a function in it. Is that normal behavior?

Comment: I don't know; I don't actually use the `ascii_art` option myself.  What is an explicit example?

Comment: For example `f=function('f'); f(x)^2` will dispplay `f(x)^2` no matter if `ascii_art` or `unicode_art` (which I found out is the Sympy style display) is on.

Comment: Looks like that would be a feature request for additions to https://github.com/sagemath/sage/tree/master/src/sage/typeset